# How to create a document term incidence matrix from long format text data?

Tags: r, nlp, tm, data-processing

I've got data that look like this:

| ID | word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blue |
| 1 | red |
| 1 | green |
| 1 | yellow |
| 2 | blue |
| 2 | purple |
| 2 | orange |
| 2 | green |

But I want to transform them into a binary incidence matrix denoting whether or not a word appears within a certain document ID. In other words, I'd like to create a matrix that looks like this:

| ID | blue | red | green | yellow | purple | orange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Is there a way to do this with the tm package? I thought maybe using DocumentTermMatrix() would work since I don't think that any words in my corpus have multiple incidences within a single document, but everything I've tried has returned error messages about the incompatibility of the function with object class data.frame

Comment: `table(df)`....

Comment: @RonakShah I get the following error, do you know how I should address it?  Error in table(df) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements This error doesn't make sense to me because my dataset is not nearly large enough to have 2^31 elements

Comment: Using another solution I found here, I tried running table(unlist(df)) instead and it ran successfully. However, it doesn't result in the output that appears in my question -- instead it counts every ID as well as the elements of the color lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this to run a supervised or unsupervised machine learning model, you should directly cast the tidy data frame into a document-feature-matrix (dfm). dfms are a class of sparse matrix that can be effectively used for these tasks. You can use `cast_dfm` from `tidytext` for this. But you have to count the occurrence of each word first.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  word = c("blue","red", "green","yellow","blue","purple","orange","green")
)

df %>% 
  count(ID, word) %>% 
  cast_dfm(ID, word, n)
#> Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 6 features (33.33% sparse) and 0 docvars.
#>     features
#> docs blue green red yellow orange purple
#>    1    1     1   1      1      0      0
#>    2    1     1   0      0      1      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can convert this object back into a data frame with `quanteda::convert(x, to = "data.frame")` but it would make more sense to use it directly if you run a classification task.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, based on `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  word = c("blue","red", "green","yellow","blue","purple","orange","green")
)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(ID, names_from = word, values_from = word,
       values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 7
#>      ID  blue   red green yellow purple orange
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1     1     1     1     1      1      0      0
#> 2     2     1     0     1      0      1      1
```

Comment: This solution looks good but I get the following error: Error: Column 2894 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.               I don't think pivot_wider accepts .name_repair as an argument, though -- do you know how to address this? Not really sure why R isn't just using the row name from the original df as the new column name.

Comment: It is hard to find out what is the problem without seeing the data, @nlplearner! You can try Ronak's suggestion of using `table(df)` instead of my solution.

Comment: It sounds like one of the "words" is an empty string. You can use `filter(word != "")` before the pivot command to solve that (if it is indeed the problem).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @JBGruber, but I do not really understand it, as my result completely matches the expected output by the OP. And, moreover, there is no empty word in the example given by the OP. Am I missing something?

Comment: I assumed that this is a small example and OP has a much larger data frame on which this should be applied. For the example, your solution works perfectly.

Comment: OK, @JBGruber, I now understand your point of view. Thanks!